# Django REST: What's the recommended approach for supporting nested collections in URLs, such as /users/5/snippets/

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The Django REST Framework [demo app](http://restframework.herokuapp.com/) exposes two collections, [/users/](http://restframework.herokuapp.com/users/) and [/snippets/](http://restframework.herokuapp.com/snippets/).

In my application, I'd like to be able to nest these collections, e.g. to load the snippets for user 5, I'd request [/users/5/snippets/](http://restframework.herokuapp.com/users/5/snippets/)

Is this sort of configuration possible in Django REST Framework? How would I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
url(r'^/sessions/(?P<session_pk>\d+)/speakers/$', views.SpeakerBySessionList.as_view()),

class SpeakerBySessionList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Speaker
    serializer_class = serializers.SpeakerSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        session_pk = self.kwargs.get('session_pk', None)
        if session_pk is not None:
            return Speaker.objects.filter(session__pk=session_pk)
        return []

class Session(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Speaker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, related_name='speakers')
```

If you want to see a more complex django / ember example be sure to checkout my github project

https://github.com/toranb/complex-ember-data-example